# Efficient way to down cast std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++11

Is there a way to do down cast of std::shared_ptr without incurring creation of a new shared_ptr and a move as its done in std::dynamic_pointer_cast?

Also there can be a scenario I am not intending to own the shared_ptr , in those case I would like to create a reference to existing shared_ptr

e.g.

```
const std::shared_ptr<derived>& d = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<derived>(b); // 
where b is std::shared_ptr<base>
```

Here I am getting a reference of b , but still paying for a temp shared_ptr.

Is there a better way apart from using raw pointers here?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pointer or reference from a `shared_ptr` and downcast it:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> b(new Derived);
auto& d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*b);
auto* d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&*b);
auto* d3 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b.get());
```

Note that destroying the original `shared_ptr` may invalidate the raw pointers and references.

Comment: This is fine as long as I am the one who is going to use it , I can deal with underlying pointer.

But What If I would need to pass it to a another function which expects shared_ptr by value or by reference of a derived?

My point is in language where dynamic polymorphism is at the heart , you can't come up with the abstraction which cost to do the up or down cast, there should be a better way to do this casting.

Comment: @user8063157 You need to pass the original `shared_ptr`, creating another `shared_ptr` from the raw pointer or reference will cause UB (double destruction).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin except if you create one with a no-op destructor, but that'd be becoming ugly.

Comment: @Quentin Thinking more about it, that function can save that shared pointer with a no-op deleter (and the only reason for a function to take a shared pointer is to save it). When the original shared pointer is destroyed, that second pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin yes, that's why it's ugly. Using `std::shared_ptr` solves the "object died too early" problem, but that kludge brings it back.